# Unable to replicate R example

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to follow along with a simple 'dplyr' group_by() example from:

https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/get-first-value-of-each-group-in-r/

For Method 2:

```
df1= data.frame(Name=c('James','Paul','Richards','Marico','Samantha','Ravi','Raghu','Richards','George','Ema','Samantha','Catherine'),
    State=c('Alaska','California','Texas','North Carolina','California','Texas','Alaska','Texas','North Carolina','Alaska','California','Texas'),
    Sales=c(14,24,31,12,13,7,9,31,18,16,18,14))
df1

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(First_value_sales = first(Sales))
```

From the website, I'm supposed to get a result that is a 4 x 2 dataframe:

```
> df1 %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(First_value_sales = first(Sales))
          State  First_value_sales
1         Alaska                14
2     California                24
3 North Carolina                12
4          Texas                31
```

But the only result I get is a 2 x 1:

```
> df1 %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(First_value_sales = first(Sales))
  First_value_sales
1                14
```

Is there any explanation for this different result from the very basic example?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably, you have loaded `plyr` and thus `plyr::summarise` masked `dplyr::summarise`.  You may try on a new R session with `dplyr` only loaded or use `dplyr::summarise` specifically instead of just `summarise`

Comment: This is exactly what happened!  Thank you so much.  I have achieved the expected result from the example.